# c++ vector crash only in 64 build - SIGBUS

Tags: c++, android-ndk, 64-bit

after uploading a 64 build of an android app i get new crash reports - `signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2 (BUS_ADRERR)`

it never happened on 32 bit arm build that was live for months before.

what can be the problem?

this is the code part that crash:

```
if (objectsInTile.size() == 0) return nullptr;

for (int i = (int)objectsInTile.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
{
    MatchObject* in = objectsInTile[i];

    //the crash happens in the bottom line
    if (in->isMainObject()) return in;
}

return nullptr;
```

Comment: Are you sure that each of the pointers in vector is valid one? There are many questionable practices here (starting from using raw pointers).

Comment: yes, it worked flawlessly before, the only change was adding 64 build type to the compile process

Comment: `it worked flawlessly before` is not an argument. UB means that incorrect code can crash or can pretend that it is "flawless" or can do strange things. I would start from analyzing crashed thread callstack, then static code analysis (clang), then try address sanitizer.

Comment: i was just able to reproduce it with debugger attached on a 64 device, the array size is 1, the i is 0 and the object in the array seems initialized with all its members at the correct values, yet it shows a sigbus error

Comment: What is the type of `objectsInTile`?

Comment: @DanAlbert std::vector<MatchObject*>

Comment: Please share the code of `MatchObject::isMainObject()`. Is **MatchObject** a derived class?

Comment: I don't suppose it's a vector with a custom allocator? `SIGBUS` often means that that some memory (in this case, the memory pointed to by `in`) that was allocated with a different alignment than the objects it is storing.

Comment: @DanAlbert Wouldn't the error code be `BUS_ADRALN` if it was an alignment issue? Or is `BUS_ADRERR` also used for that purpose?

Comment: Good point. I'm not actually sure.